# How to I add my app's docs to be accessed via the app, but not via the public directory? (so authentication is required)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE:

I'm getting this error:

```
(No route matches "/docs/index.html"... )
```

when accessing

```
admin.example.com/docs/index.html
```

The file exists.

In my routes.rb file:

```
map.with_options(:conditions => {:subdomain => 'admin']}) do |subdom|
    subdom.root :controller => 'admin/subscriptions', :action => 'index'
    subdom.with_options(:namespace => 'admin/', :name_prefix => 'admin_', :path_prefix => nil) do |admin|
        admin.connect "/docs/:id", :controller => :docs, :action => :get_file
    end
end
```

and the docs controller is in app/controllers/admin/

the only method in that controller

```
def get_file
        path = request.request_uri
        send_file(path)
    end
```

END UPDATE

So, I have a subdomain, admin.example.com, that I would like to put YARD generated docs behind.

I tried just putting them in the public folder, and modifying the routes.rb file, but the docs were always accessible.

How do I make it so that they are only available once logged in to admin.example.com?

(all the href's in the docs are relative, so, I'm not sure how I'd use controllers, either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your method should look like:

```
def get_file
    path = Dir[Rails.root.join("docs", params[:file_or_folder])]
    if path.length > 0
        # check if root directory
        path_str = path[0]
        if path_str =~ /\/docs\/?\z/
            path_str += "/index.html"
        end
        render :file => path_str
    else
        render :text => "File Not Found"
    end

end
```

And your rails route should look like this:

```
map.connect "/docs/:file_or_folder", :controller => :docs, :action => :get_file, :file_or_folder => /.*/
map.resources :docs, :only => :get_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them in the public folder.

Put them somewhere else entirely and stream them back to authenticated users only.

One way to do this is to [use `send_file`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file).

Comment: how? do I stream them to those users?

Comment: @TheLindyHop Perhaps using `send_file` (updated answer with link), although there are likely other ways.

Comment: but.. lets say I have href="/myObject.html", how do I send that file? the params hash loses that information when my routes tells anything with doc/ to use the get_file action... =\

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/637725747/nginx-rails-send-file) a good primer on how you could accomplish protecting files from the public using nginx and send_file.